# McAfee ePolicy Orchestrator SQL Server Licensing

Tags: mcafee

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing issue?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-issue)

I am going to install McAfee ePO with SQL Server 2008 R2. But I am not 100% sure about the SQL Server License required for ePO. The plan is to install McAfee server, ePO and SQL Server all on one common server, which means no other service will use the SQL Server (it will be exclusive to ePO). My question is, which SQL Server license do I need for this scenario SQL Processor license or SQL Server license (with CAL)?

Thanks.

Comment: Does that product not come with SQL Server Express Edition? If it does then use that. If it doesn't then I would download and install SQL Server Express Edition seperately and use it.

Comment: Yes, it comes with Express. My scenario is, someone has already installed ePO and SQL Server Server license. So, I wanted to know if Server license with CAL is sufficient or not.

Answer (score 1):

We can't help you with your software licensing issue, contact your MS rep.  [Having said that, here's a doc from Microsoft about the difference between per core and Server/CAL licensing for SQL Server 2012](http://download.microsoft.com/download/7/3/C/73CAD4E0-D0B5-4BE5-AB49-D5B886A5AE00/SQL_Server_2012_Licensing_Reference_Guide.pdf) that you can use to decide for yourself.